# Subdividing a div into a 4 more divs and position them at NE, SE, NW and SW directions

Tags: html, css

I need to draw something like this using html and css. I am not able to do so.

```
          _____________________
          |      |      |     |  
          |______|      |_____|
          |                   |  
          |______        _____|
          |      |       |    |
          |______|_______|____|
```

I created a major div, an outer rectangle and then created 4 nested divs, smaller rectangular. For the left side 2 i made them to float left and the other 2 float to right. But it is not something that i want. Can someone please let me know what should be done.

Comment: What are the width of the outer and the inner rectangles? Or are they squares?

Comment: @biziclop: Assume they are squares. The purpose is , I have a bigger div(many of them). Now i need to divide them and as per the diagram and load some data on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use absolution positioning to achieve this. The absolution position of each inner div would have two of `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` set to 0.

Here's an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS Based layouts</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #rect {
              width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                position: relative;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #topleft {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
                left: 0;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #bottomleft {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #topright {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
                right: 0;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #bottomright {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CSS Based layouts</h1>
        <p></p>

        <div id="rect">

            <div id="topleft">
                Top and Left
            </div>
            <div id="bottomleft">
                Bottom and Left
            </div>
            <div id="topright">
                Top and Right
            </div>
            <div id="bottomright">
                Bottom and Right
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does work. Thanks a lot. I was not including the position and there I was doing it wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I would avoid using absolute positioning as some browsers interpretation of the box model is incorrect. This creates inconsistencies in the placement of content, since absolute zero is not in the same spot for all of them. (e.g. sometimes this is caused by browsers incorrectly determining the parent element, therefore 0,0 is not at the top left corner as it should be, but possibly somewhere else)

Comment: @PaulCalabro Are you referring to just IE or some other browsers too? There are hacks to fix IE's box model issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use Absolute Positioning  see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NPALD/

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="NW"></div>
    <div id="NE"></div>
    <div id="SW"></div>
    <div id="SE"></div>
</div>
​
#outer
{
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    position: relative;
}
#NW, #NE, #SW, #SE {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
#NW
{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#NE
{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#SW
{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#SE
{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout seems to be tabular, so let's try tables:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvTak/2/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="t l">Top Left</td>
        <td class="t r">Top Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="b l">Bottom Left</td>
        <td class="b r">Bottom Right</td>
     </tr>
</table>​

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.l {
    border-right: 100px solid yellow;
}

.t {
    border-bottom: 100px solid yellow;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am more interested in using the divs, than using the table